# How to use the word 'Elect' in these sentences correctly?

Tags: vocabulary, word-order

> 1) I was elected to debate about British History with Exchange Students.
>
> 2) I was elected Faculty of Arts representative to compete in ...

Comment: I see! Is No 1 already correct?

Comment: I think so, but let's wait for a native speaker to confirm it.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're very welcome! :)

Comment: (2) You can certainly be _elected President_ or _elected as President_ – both variants are fine. However, I think not using the 'as' does connote a prestige that the president of a nation has whereas a representative of a faculty might not. // (1) There is a usage, _elect + to-infinitive_ = _choose + to-infinitive_ (I elected to eat in the refectory) (very formal), but 'I was elected to debate about X' with the intended meaning 'I was chosen to debate about X' sounds very rarefied (unless there's a position, say Chief Debater, involved). 'Put forward', 'chosen' or 'selected'.

Comment: Thanks, Edwin! So I was wrong that an article is needed, Tintin. And 'as' is also better to omit here, according to Edwin. So I'll delete that comment. Nice question, voted for it.

Comment: They are both correct. *Faculty of Arts representative* is a retained objective complement (grammar terms vary); *as* is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you all !:)